# Use image in Sphinx as clickable link

Tags: html, image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

**Problem**:

I have a table of images that I'm using as an overview/introduction. I want the end-user to be able to click on the image and it link to the HTML page for that image's corresponding introductory information<sup>1</sup>.

The problem is I can't seem to get the linking part to work. The table of images shows up fine, but clicking on an image just takes me to a page not found screen (see image at bottom of post). I've spent about an hour on Google but haven't found a solution yet.

<sup>1</sup>each image has a corresponding .rst file with the info I want the end-user to see

---

**Info:**

- Sphinx 1.8.5
- Python 3.7.6 (MiniConda)
- Building html pages from reStructuredText files

  - `sphinx-build -b html source build`
  - `make clean html`
  - `make html`
- Nothing special has been done in my conf.py file, other than including the RTD theme

  - I'm guessing I will need to do something fancy in my conf.py file **if** doing what I want is possible at all
- Adding the .rst files to the `.. toc::` directive in `introduction_file.rst` didn't help

---

**Here is the reST code I have so far:**

- *the image directives are all inside a table; table omitted for brevity*
- *I'm also confident that the 'image directives inside a table' thing is not the issue*

```
    .. filename is "introduction_file.rst"
    
    .. image:: images/my_first_image.png
       :scale: 100%
       :alt: My First PNG Image
       :align: center
       :target: introduction_files/my_first_image_intro_file.rst

    .. also didn't work:
    .. :target: introduction_files/my_first_image_intro_file.html
```

---

**File Structure:**

- *`Home.rst` is the entry point for the HTML pages (i.e. it used to be called `index.rst` until I renamed it and refactored `conf.py` accordingly)*

```
--build
    ...
-- source
   |--Introduction/
      |--introduction_file.rst
      |--images/
         |--my_first_image.png
         |--my_second_image.png
             ...
      |--introduction_files/
         |--my_first_image_intro_file.rst
         |--my_second_image_intro_file.rst
             ...
   |--_static/
       ...
   |--_templates/
       ...
   |--conf.py
   |--Home.rst
```

---

I'm not opposed to doing what I want in HTML/CSS, but if there is a way to do it in sphinx then I'd prefer to do it that way. I will end up editing the HTML code regardless, but the less editing the better; Sphinx is essentially a quick-start or template.

---

This image is what I see in my browser when I click on one of the images in my table-of-images. The URL bar in Chrome shows the correct path to the .rst file though, so I'm a bit confused.

- I tried changing the `:target:` file extension to `.html` but that didn't work either

[image: Result of clicking on the images]

---

**Edit**: forgot to add the location of `introduction_file.rst` to the folder structure

---

---

**Solution**:

Mix up between the paths. I was linking to the file in the source directory, but needed to link to the file in the build directory. Had to navigate back to the root directory with a few '../' prefixes, then navigate to the .html information file in the build directory. In other words, this is what it ended up looking like:

```
    .. filename is "introduction_file.rst"
    
    .. image:: images/my_first_image.png
       :scale: 100%
       :alt: My First PNG Image
       :align: center
       :target: ../../../build/html/Introduction/introduction_files/my_first_image_intro_file.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` option's value must be either relative to `introduction_file.rst` (you don't provide its location so you'll have to figure that out), or absolute to the documentation root, i.e., `/Introduction/introduction_files/my_first_image_intro_file.html`.

Comment: Forgot to add it to the folder structure, have edited. I think I've got it relative to introduction_file.rst though.

Comment: `./introduction_files/my_first_image_intro_file.html` did not work? If not, try the absolute path I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Figured it out. I was linking to the file in the source directory, but needed to link to the file in the build directory. Several '../' + 'filename.stem' + '.html' later and it is going where it is supposed to now.